# overpass query took long time and no response

Tags: java, overpass-api

I have a list with 900 (lat,lon) sets.
I used a loop to query each (lat,lon). 
It stuck on 3rd set (48.55888888888889,12.404166666666667) and had no response.

My language is Java and reference this example([example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=osm-common-master/core/src/main/java/se/kodapan/osm/services/overpass/Overpass.java)).

The stuck line is `HttpResponse response = getHttpClient().execute(post);`

below is my query

`[out:json][timeout:100];(way(around:5000,lat,lon)["waterway"="river"];way(around:5000,lat,lon)["waterway"="riverbank"];way(around:5000,lat,lon)["waterway"="waterfall"];way(around:5000,lat,lon)["tunnel"="*"];way(around:5000,lat,lon)["landuse"="forest"];way(around:5000,lat,lon)["natural"="water"];way(around:5000,lat,lon)["natural"="coastline"];way(around:5000,lat,lon)["natural"="geyser"];way(around:5000,lat,lon)["natural"="bay"];way(around:5000,lat,lon)["natural"="beach"];);
(._;>;);out body;`

It can work on overpass turbo and take about 5 secs.
[overpass_query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/?q=W291dDpqc29uXVt0aW1lxIHEgzEwMF07KHdheShhcsSBbmQ6NcSSMCw0OC41NTjEqsSrxKw4OSwxMi40MDQxNsS4xLnEujcpWyLEl3RlcsSXeSI9InJpdsWCIsSUxYTEmsScdcSexKDEosSkxKbEqMStxZnEr8SxxLPEtcS3xLrFoMS8xL7FgMWCxYTFhsWIxYrFgmJhbmvFjTvFj8SbxJ3En8ShxJLFlsSnxKnFmcSsxZvEssS0xLbFoMWhxL3Ev2HFgcWDxJjFp8WkcmZhbGzFr8WxxZHFk8W1xKPEpcW4xbrFu8Swxb3FnsaAxLvGgnTFkm5lxo7FhyrGj8SYxZDFs8WUxbbGlcWYxpfEqsW8xZ3Fv8acxLjFoiJsxaxkdXNlxadmb3Jlc3TGpsSZxbLFksW0xZXGrMW5xq7GsMW-xZ_Gs8a1bsaEdXLGjMaIxoTFjMWOxqfHhsaSx4nFl8eLxpfHjcabxrM2x5HHk8eVxqMiY29hx4Jsacahx4TGqMeHxqrGlMefxq7Gr8aZxrHHj8acx6bGn8eoxadnZXnGu3LHssecx4jGq8e3x7jHosayx5DGgseSx7_HlsWHxavFhceax4XGkciJx7bGlsiMx7rHjsekx6XIkMenyJMiYmVhY2jFrynElS5fOz47yKzEjyBib2R5Owo&c=BOwJW-TL2M)

could any one give me some suggestions?

Comment: I guess you're getting something like a HTTP 429, because you're sending too many queries in a too short timeframe. Check the results of http://overpass-api.de/api/status, add more wait time in your loop.

Comment: @mmd you're right ! I checked the respond and got **Error</strong>: runtime error: open64: 0 Success /osm3s_v0.7.54_osm_base Dispatcher_Client::request_read_and_idx::rate_limited. Please check /api/status for the quota of your IP address.** I tried to use  `InputStream.close()` to deallocate resource but not work. I'm looking for another way~

Comment: Yes, that's a very clear sign that you're exceeding your quota. You need to slow down a bit with your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for @mmd 's response help me to solve this problem.
[status](http://overpass-api.de/api/status) can check the resource you can use. My problem is allocate the resource. There are 2 slot available for each IP. I printed the response from overpass and got **Error: runtime error: open64: 0 Success /osm3s_v0.7.54_osm_base Dispatcher_Client::request_read_and_idx::rate_limited. Please check /api/status for the quota of your IP address.**

My solution is add `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);` before httppost and add `response.getEntity().getContent().close();` after getting the result.

Finally it works!